# Eclipse won't recognize G-tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, tablet

I am trying to view a sample app on a real device (a ViewSonic G-tablet), but the device won't display in the "Choose a running Android device" area. The virtual devices show, but no real devices show (there is only one plugged in, the G-tablet). Some other information...

- I am using a Mac with Eclipse SDK 3.7.1 w/Android
- App is noted as debuggable in manifest file (android:debuggable="true")
- G-Tablet is set to allow debugging
- Device selection is set to manual in SDK
- I CAN view files on G-Tablet using Finder
- I have reviewed Android developer docs
- I have searched a lot online for a fix, without success

Please also note...

- There is NO option on G-tablet to allow "unknown sources". However, I have downloaded apps outside the customary channels (e.g. Firefox from the Firefox site) and it works fine.
- I do NOT want to do anything to the G-tablet to void the warranty.
- I have already checked for/installed updates using the Android SDK Manager.
- The fixes I was able to find on StackOverflow related to this problem did not work for me. I am thinking the problem may be device specific. One fix discussed getting a driver for the device, but I couldn't find one.

Can anyone please help me figure out how to get the SDK to recognize my device? I'd appreciate any insight on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after trying a zillion things. All that needed to be done to fix the problem was turn to OFF 'USB debugging' and then turn it right back on. I found the idea on this page... http://www.mobileread.mobi/forums/showthread.php?t=156247 . Hope that might save someone else hours of time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you export the app as an .apk and run that on your G-tablet?

also is the android:minSdkVersion set to a value lower than your G-tablet's version?

Comment: Thanks for your response. To answer your first question, I haven't tried exporting as an .apk yet as I was just hoping to test on the device the first time. For your second question, the target is android-7, and the g-tablet is froyo (api level 8), so I should be okay on that. Do you have any idea why it won't recognize my device? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.